# Find matching object keys from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects all with the same property names, with javascript how would you create a new object made up of key:value pairs that are found in all the objects of the array?

For example, given:

```
[
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'urg',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  }
]
```

Result:

```
{
  b: 'bar',
  c: 'zip'
}
```

Comment: do you want to find unique of `key:value` !?

Comment: If I can assume that there are the same amount of properties in each object of the array, you create a new object for your output, then for each property of the object in the array iterate through the array checking if that value is constant throughout all items.

Comment: @Xupitan I'm not sure I understand your question. But I think the answer to your question is yes. Like the example I gave in the question. return each key:value pair that exists in each object.

Comment: @code yes each object has the same properties. Your answer was the first thought I had. Just wondering if there is a more eloquent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Start with all the elements of the first item (cloned, because we don't want to change the original data), then remove any key-value pairs that do not show up in the subsequent items:

```js
const data = [
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'urg',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  }
];

const [first, ...rest] = data;
const result = rest.reduce((a, e) => {
  Object.keys(a).forEach(k => {
    if (!k in e || e[k] !== a[k]) {
      delete a[k];
    }
  });
  return a;
}, {...first});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "How would you create a *new* object..." whatever, a shallow copy would do.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare each value in the first object with every other object.

```js
const [first, ...others] = [
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'urg',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  },
  {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'zip'
  }
];


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(first)) {
    for (const object of others) {
        if (object[key] !== value) {
            delete first[key];
        }
    }
}

console.log(first);
```

Comment: What if the first object has keys that don't exist in subsequent objects?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Any key that doesn't exist in the first object, by definition, can't exist in all of the objects.

Comment: You might want to re-read my comment.

Comment: Oh, good spotting.

Comment: I updated the question. All the objects have the same properties.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Found the solution to be comparing the first object to every other object rather than comparing each object to the first.

Comment: Yup, that's it.